# Same Joining happens twice in linq query

Tags: linq

I am very new to `Linq` and I am trying to some kind of a filtering.

```
 var customers = from c in Customers select c;


if (regDate.HasValue)
    customers = from c customers
            join p in CustomerProducts on c.Id equals p.CusId
            where dss.rate == rate
            select c;

if (productName.HasValue)
    customers = from c customers
                join cp in CustomerProducts on c.Id equals cp.CusId
                join p in Products on cp.pId equals p.Id
                where p.Name == pName
                select c;

.....
.....
```

In a situation where both **regDate, productName** has value following join happens twice

```
join p in CustomerProducts on c.Id equals p.CusId
```

**Since I new to this I have no idea whether this case makes any bad effect. please advice. me.**

Comment: Basically, if they both have values then customers will get overwritten with the value of your second query. Not sure if that is what you want.  Also, it won't have any bad effect because the queries will be ran independently of each other.

Comment: Yes. that is fine and that is what i need to do. But is this a bad coding? since same join happens twice.

Comment: You can probably tidy it up so that if regDate has a value AND productName has a value then it only runs one query then you can do your either or query.  Running the queries twice just adds to your overhead is all.